# Match scrolling inside div to another outside div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've tried getting this to work on JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/sgcer/3132/

I currently have the two divs scrolling in sync, div#top and div#bottom,  however I actually want the #bottom div to scroll in sync with the div#top content that is scrolling, i.e the text inside the div not the container div. Any help is greatly appreciated!

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="top">
    <p>first column</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
  </div>
  </div>
<div id="bottom">
    <p>second column content</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
    <p>Content Here</p>
</div>
```

css

```
 .container {
  width: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 315px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: scroll;
  top: 20px;
}
#top {
  left: 0;

}


#bottom {
  top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left       : 50%;
    overflow   : auto;
    overflow-x : scroll;
    overflow-y : auto;
}
```

jQuery

```
 $('#bottom').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#top').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured it out with the help of this plugin if anyone else wants to do this.

Install this plugin:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Synchronize-Scrolling-Across-Elements-jQuery-ScrollSync/

Then to get it to do what I wanted, my code:

html

```
   <div class="content">
      <p>content to be scrolled to</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container container-2">
    <div class="container container-2">
      <div class="content-2">
        <p class='p-text'>content in container 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
 body { padding-bottom: 100px; padding-top: 100px; }

    .container {
      float: left;
      width: 33.3%;
      height: 400px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }

    .container-2{
      margin-left: 100px;
      width: 30vw;
    }

    .content-2 {
      box-sizing:border-box;
      float: left;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 1000px;
      /* background-color: pink; */
      margin-top: 50px;
    }

      .p-text {
        background-color: purple;
      }

    .content{
      box-sizing:border-box;
      float: left;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 1000px;
      background-color: #E74C3C;
    }
```

js

```
$('.container').scrollsync();
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`(function() {`
    `var target = $("#bottom");`
    `$("#top").scroll(function() {`
    `target.prop("scrollTop", this.scrollTop)`
       `.prop("scrollLeft", this.scrollLeft);`
  `});`
`})();`

This will work.

When you scroll top, it will scroll bottom div also.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I've added your answer into jsfiddle, but it isn't doing what I wanted. I think I haven't explained the problem very well. I can get both divs to scroll when I scroll the first one ( the blue div) but actually what I am wanting is that the second (pink) div scrolls with the inside **contents** of the first div. so the first div, has overflow scroll, on the p tags, and I am wanting the second div to scroll with the p tag content.. does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: I'll try this another way because I think it's not clear.
So the top of the pink div is aligned with the first line of text of the blue div "<p>first column</p>".
When I scroll the contents of the blue div up or down, I want the pink div to also scroll up and down and align with the first line of text in the blue div.
http://jsfiddle.net/Lt06mpz4/

Comment: I have placed the scrolling of pink element based on scrolling of blue div.